# Get lines between starting and ending keywords in text file, then do post processing using python

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I have a text file, I would like to extract the lines between starting (Socket:) and ending keywords (Socket:), then do a processing.

Input:

```
Socket: 1
Device ID: 0x0B028041 0xCC344007 0x10000834 0x00000011
CB: 3/ID: 0x445DDC13
BIBID: 0x65C     

A:0xB0000190 D:0x310020FF
A:0xB0000194 D:0x00000000
A:0xB0000198 D:0x31002010
A:0xB000019C D:0x00000017
A:0xB00001A0 D:0x31002020
A:0xB00001A4 D:0x00000017
A:0xB00001A8 D:0x31002040
A:0xB00001AC D:0x00000000
A:0xB00001B0 D:0x31001000
ART: 0xB0000800 DRT: 0xB0000000
ART: 0xB0000804 DRT: 0xB0000000
ART: 0xB0000808 DRT: 0xB0000000
ART: 0xB000080C DRT: 0xB0000000
ART: 0xB0000810 DRT: 0xB0000000
ART: 0xB0000814 DRT: 0xB0000000
ART: 0xB0000818 DRT: 0xB0000000
ART: 0xB000081C DRT: 0xB0000000
ART: 0xB0000820 DRT: 0xB0000000
ART: 0xB0000824 DRT: 0xB0000000
ART: 0xB0000828 DRT: 0xB0000000
ART: 0xB000082C DRT: 0xB0000000
ART: 0xB0000830 DRT: 0xB0000000
ART: 0xB0000834 DRT: 0xB0000000
ART: 0xB0000838 DRT: 0xB0000000
ART: 0xB000083C DRT: 0xB0000000
ART: 0xB0000840 DRT: 0xB0000000
ART: 0xB0000844 DRT: 0xB0000000
ART: 0xB0000848 DRT: 0xB0000000
ART: 0xB000084C DRT: 0xB0000000
ART: 0xB0000850 DRT: 0xB0000000
ART: 0xB0000854 DRT: 0xB0000000
ART: 0xB0000858 DRT: 0xB0000000
ART: 0xB000085C DRT: 0xB0000000
ART: 0xB0000860 DRT: 0xB0000000
ART: 0xB0000864 DRT: 0xB0000000
ART: 0xB0000868 DRT: 0xB0000000
ART: 0xB000086C DRT: 0xB0000000
ART: 0xB0000870 DRT: 0xB0000000
ART: 0xB0000874 DRT: 0xB0000000
ART: 0xB0000878 DRT: 0xB0000000
ART: 0xB000087C DRT: 0xB0000000
...
Socket:2
...
```

Current Code:

```
    import re

    from collections import defaultdict
    dict2=defaultdict(list)
    dict3=defaultdict(list)
    socket_position_status = False
    dev_id_status = False
    CB_noS_status = False
    trf_val_flag = False
    dict1=defaultdict(list)
    pattern="QWL"
    rd_case= "Digital"
    setup_temp = "0C"
    readout_temp = "0C"
    address=[]

    def tde_file():
        with open(r'C:\Gert_batch file\DOE_parsing\Thebe\DOE 4 - 5K\NEW SFR\PF\tde\MRB_QWL_0c_Digital_PS60c_TC1798.tde', 'rb') as f:
            for line in f:
                pattern_tde = ":TEST_RESULT"
                if pattern_tde in line:

                    tde_addr = ':TEST_RESULT (\d+); addr: ([0-9A-Za-z]{10})'
                    x0 =re.match(tde_addr, line)

                    if x0:
                        address_tde = x0.group(2)
                        tde_addr_1 = 'cfp_(vqs|vcs)_m(\d+) \// HB05_SB255'
                        x1 = re.search(tde_addr_1,line)

                        tde_addr_2 = 'cfp_(vqs|vcs)_m\dm\d_(vth\d.\d) \// HB05_SB255'
                        x2 = re.search(tde_addr_2,line)

                        tde_addrs_1 = '(DTS_)value_(before|after)_test_(start|finish)'
                        y0 = re.search(tde_addrs_1,line)

                        if x1:
                            hlp_s = x1.group(2).zfill(2)
                            identifier =  x1.group(1)+"_m"+hlp_s

                        if x2:
                            identifier =  x2.group(1)+"_m"+x2.group(2)

                        try:
                            tde_addr_3 = '(SBE|DBE)|(Number of (\ds) bit fail) \// HB05_SB255'
                            hlp_s = re.search(tde_addr_3,line).group(1)
                            if hlp_s:
                                dict1[pattern,rd_case,address_tde]=identifier+"_"+hlp_s

                        except AttributeError:pass

                        try:
                            tde_addr_3 = '(SBE|DBE)|(Number of (\ds) bit fail) \// HB05_SB255'
                            hlp_s = re.search(tde_addr_3,line).group(3)
                            if hlp_s:
                                dict1[pattern,rd_case,address_tde]=identifier+"_"+hlp_s

                        except AttributeError: pass

                        try:
                            if y0.group(1) and y0.group(3):
                                dict1[pattern,rd_case,address_tde]=y0.group(1)+y0.group(3)+"_temp"
                        except AttributeError: pass
        #print dict1
        #print len(dict1.keys())
        #for k,v in sorted(dict1.items()):
            #print k,v


    def evaluate_lot_wxy(trf_dev_id_pattern):
        import re
        binary_value = ""

        line = trf_dev_id_pattern
        dev_id = 'Device ID: ([0-9a-zA-Z]{10}) ([0-9a-zA-Z]{10}) ([0-9a-zA-Z]{10}) ([0-9a-zA-Z]{10})$'
        hex_inp1 = re.search(dev_id,line)
        #print hex_inp1.group()
        hex_inp2 = hex_inp1.group(4)+hex_inp1.group(3)+hex_inp1.group(2)+hex_inp1.group(1)
        hex_inp3 =  re.sub('0x', '', hex_inp2)
        #print hex_inp3
        for i,val in enumerate(str(hex_inp3)):
            binary_value1=str(bin(int(val,16))[2:]).zfill(4)
            binary_value = str(binary_value) + str(binary_value1)
        #print binary_value

        wafer_val = binary_value[90:96]
        wafer = int(wafer_val,2)
        y_pos_val = binary_value[106:113]
        y_pos = int(y_pos_val,2)
        x_pos_val = binary_value[98:105]
        x_pos = int(x_pos_val,2)
        year_val = binary_value[63:67]
        year = int(year_val,2)
        production_week_val = binary_value[67:73]
        production_week = int(production_week_val,2)
        serial_no_val = binary_value[73:83]
        serial_no=int(serial_no_val,2)
        lot ="ZA"+str(year)+str(production_week)+str(serial_no)
        if (1 <= wafer <= 25) and (1<= x_pos <= 65) and (1 <= y_pos <= 65):
            dev_id_status = True
        return lot,wafer,x_pos,y_pos,dev_id_status

    tde_file()

    with open(r"C:\Gert_batch file\DOE_parsing\Thebe\DOE 4 - 5K\NEW SFR\PF\1kCycling\Results_452_13384\Result     Files\temp\452_20170111_021021_TC1798_MRB_QWL_0c_Digital_PS60c_1021002999.trf", "rt") as f1:
    lines = f1.read()
    print lines
    #for lines in f1.read():

    match = re.search(r'Socket:(.*?)Socket:', lines, flags=re.DOTALL)
    #print match.group()
    for line in match.group().splitlines():
        if "Socket:" in line:
            trf_addr = 'Socket: (\d+)$'
            x0 =re.match(trf_addr, line)
            try:
                if x0.group(1).zfill(3):
                    socket_position = x0.group(1).zfill(3)
                    socket_position_status = True
                    #print socket_position


            except AttributeError: pass

        elif "Device ID:" in line:
            dev_id = 'Device ID: ([0-9a-zA-Z]{10}) ([0-9a-zA-Z]{10}) ([0-9a-zA-Z]{10}) ([0-9a-zA-Z]{10})$'
            x1 = re.search(dev_id,line)
            try:
                if  x1.group(1) and x1.group(1) and x1.group(1) and x1.group(1):
                    trf_dev_id_pattern = x1.group()#x1.group(4)+x1.group(3)+x1.group(2)+x1.group(1)
                    lot_wafer_x_y = evaluate_lot_wxy(trf_dev_id_pattern)
                    dev_id_status = True
                    #print lot_wafer_x_y

            except AttributeError: pass

        elif "CB:" in line:
            CB_pat = 'CB: (\d+)\/'
            x2 = re.search(CB_pat,line)
            try:
                if  x2.group(1):
                    CB_noS_status = True
                    #print CB_noS_status
            except AttributeError: pass

        elif"ART:" in line:
            regex = re.search("ART: ([0-9A-Za-z]{10}) DRT: ([0-9A-Za-z]{10})",line)
            #print line
            try:
                if regex.group(1) and regex.group(2):
                    for key1,val1 in dict1.iteritems():
                        if regex.group(1) in key1:
                            #print "Address:"+regex.group(1)
                            hlp_a = val1
                            hlp_b = hlp_a.split("_")
                            identifier = hlp_b[0]
                            fail_class = hlp_b[1]
                            key_addtional = hlp_b[2]
                            val = regex.group(2)
                            value = int(val[3:],16)
                            dict2[rd_case,pattern,setup_temp,readout_temp,socket_position,fail_class,identifier,key_addtional]= value        

            except AttributeError: pass

    for k,v in sorted(dict2.items()):
        print k,v
```

Current Output:

Currently the code is print the output for the first match and I would like to get the output for the entire match in the input file.

```
('Digital', 'QWL', '0C', '0C', '001', 'finish', 'DTS', 'temp') 16
('Digital', 'QWL', '0C', '0C', '001', 'm02', 'vqs', '0s') 0
('Digital', 'QWL', '0C', '0C', '001', 'm02', 'vqs', '1s') 0
('Digital', 'QWL', '0C', '0C', '001', 'm02', 'vqs', 'DBE') 0
('Digital', 'QWL', '0C', '0C', '001', 'm02', 'vqs', 'SBE') 0
('Digital', 'QWL', '0C', '0C', '001', 'm03', 'vqs', '0s') 0
('Digital', 'QWL', '0C', '0C', '001', 'm03', 'vqs', '1s') 0
('Digital', 'QWL', '0C', '0C', '001', 'm03', 'vqs', 'DBE') 0
('Digital', 'QWL', '0C', '0C', '001', 'm03', 'vqs', 'SBE') 0
('Digital', 'QWL', '0C', '0C', '001', 'm04', 'vqs', '0s') 0
('Digital', 'QWL', '0C', '0C', '001', 'm04', 'vqs', '1s') 0
('Digital', 'QWL', '0C', '0C', '001', 'm04', 'vqs', 'DBE') 0
('Digital', 'QWL', '0C', '0C', '001', 'm04', 'vqs', 'SBE') 0
('Digital', 'QWL', '0C', '0C', '001', 'm05', 'vqs', '0s') 0
('Digital', 'QWL', '0C', '0C', '001', 'm05', 'vqs', '1s') 0
('Digital', 'QWL', '0C', '0C', '001', 'm05', 'vqs', 'DBE') 0
('Digital', 'QWL', '0C', '0C', '001', 'm05', 'vqs', 'SBE') 0
('Digital', 'QWL', '0C', '0C', '001', 'm06', 'vqs', '0s') 0
('Digital', 'QWL', '0C', '0C', '001', 'm06', 'vqs', '1s') 0
('Digital', 'QWL', '0C', '0C', '001', 'm06', 'vqs', 'DBE') 0
('Digital', 'QWL', '0C', '0C', '001', 'm06', 'vqs', 'SBE') 0
('Digital', 'QWL', '0C', '0C', '001', 'm07', 'vqs', '0s') 0
('Digital', 'QWL', '0C', '0C', '001', 'm07', 'vqs', '1s') 0
('Digital', 'QWL', '0C', '0C', '001', 'm07', 'vqs', 'DBE') 0
('Digital', 'QWL', '0C', '0C', '001', 'm07', 'vqs', 'SBE') 0
('Digital', 'QWL', '0C', '0C', '001', 'm08', 'vqs', '0s') 0
('Digital', 'QWL', '0C', '0C', '001', 'm08', 'vqs', '1s') 0
('Digital', 'QWL', '0C', '0C', '001', 'm08', 'vqs', 'DBE') 0
('Digital', 'QWL', '0C', '0C', '001', 'm08', 'vqs', 'SBE') 0
('Digital', 'QWL', '0C', '0C', '001', 'm09', 'vqs', '0s') 0
('Digital', 'QWL', '0C', '0C', '001', 'm09', 'vqs', '1s') 0
('Digital', 'QWL', '0C', '0C', '001', 'm09', 'vqs', 'DBE') 0
('Digital', 'QWL', '0C', '0C', '001', 'm09', 'vqs', 'SBE') 0
('Digital', 'QWL', '0C', '0C', '001', 'm10', 'vqs', '0s') 0
('Digital', 'QWL', '0C', '0C', '001', 'm10', 'vqs', '1s') 0
('Digital', 'QWL', '0C', '0C', '001', 'm10', 'vqs', 'DBE') 0
('Digital', 'QWL', '0C', '0C', '001', 'm10', 'vqs', 'SBE') 0
('Digital', 'QWL', '0C', '0C', '001', 'm11', 'vqs', '0s') 0
('Digital', 'QWL', '0C', '0C', '001', 'm11', 'vqs', '1s') 0
('Digital', 'QWL', '0C', '0C', '001', 'm11', 'vqs', 'DBE') 0
('Digital', 'QWL', '0C', '0C', '001', 'm11', 'vqs', 'SBE') 0
('Digital', 'QWL', '0C', '0C', '001', 'm12', 'vqs', '0s') 0
('Digital', 'QWL', '0C', '0C', '001', 'm12', 'vqs', '1s') 0
('Digital', 'QWL', '0C', '0C', '001', 'm12', 'vqs', 'DBE') 0
('Digital', 'QWL', '0C', '0C', '001', 'm12', 'vqs', 'SBE') 0
('Digital', 'QWL', '0C', '0C', '001', 'm13', 'vqs', '0s') 0
('Digital', 'QWL', '0C', '0C', '001', 'm13', 'vqs', '1s') 0
('Digital', 'QWL', '0C', '0C', '001', 'm13', 'vqs', 'DBE') 0
('Digital', 'QWL', '0C', '0C', '001', 'm13', 'vqs', 'SBE') 0
('Digital', 'QWL', '0C', '0C', '001', 'm14', 'vqs', '0s') 0
('Digital', 'QWL', '0C', '0C', '001', 'm14', 'vqs', '1s') 0
('Digital', 'QWL', '0C', '0C', '001', 'm14', 'vqs', 'DBE') 0
('Digital', 'QWL', '0C', '0C', '001', 'm14', 'vqs', 'SBE') 0
('Digital', 'QWL', '0C', '0C', '001', 'm15', 'vqs', '0s') 0
('Digital', 'QWL', '0C', '0C', '001', 'm15', 'vqs', '1s') 0
('Digital', 'QWL', '0C', '0C', '001', 'm15', 'vqs', 'DBE') 0
('Digital', 'QWL', '0C', '0C', '001', 'm15', 'vqs', 'SBE') 0
('Digital', 'QWL', '0C', '0C', '001', 'start', 'DTS', 'temp') 14
```

The above is the output for first match, but I would like to get the output for every match in the file. Could anyone help me in this ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
import re
txt = '''Test_Socket: 1

TestA ID: 0x0B028041 0xCC344007 0x10000834 0x00000011

TestA_CB: 3/ID: 0x445DDC13

TESTA_BD: 0x65C

A:0xB0000190 D:0x310020FF

ART: 0xB0000878 DRT: 0xB0000000

ART: 0xB000087C DRT: 0xB0000000 ... Test_Socket:2'''

match = re.search(r'Test_Socket:(.*?)Test_Socket:', txt, flags=re.DOTALL)
print(match.group(1))
```

code outputs:

```
TestA ID: 0x0B028041 0xCC344007 0x10000834 0x00000011

TestA_CB: 3/ID: 0x445DDC13

TESTA_BD: 0x65C

A:0xB0000190 D:0x310020FF

ART: 0xB0000878 DRT: 0xB0000000

ART: 0xB000087C DRT: 0xB0000000 ...
```

after extracting the lines your can iterate them or run another regex to get what you need from these lines.

```
for line in match.group(1).splitlines():
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I am getting error like TypeError: expected string or buffer.

Comment: you can test it [here](https://repl.it/FSdG) please add more info about what not working

Comment: I am getting the same error. how to add a screen shot here?

Comment: please take a look I added a snippet online on the comment above which works. can you try diff your input and this? what python version are you using? what operating system?

Comment: Thank you, I will try and get back to you. I am using win7 os and python 2.7.

Comment: Hi, it is working, but it is working only for the first finding. Not able to loop through the entire file...

Comment: can you the minimal text example you trying to parse and the output you prefer?

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I have added these details in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, I have tried re.finditer() in regex and it is working as expected. Please find my code, if there is a better approach than this, plz let me know. I would like thank everyone.

CODE:

```
import re

from collections import defaultdict
dict2=defaultdict(list)
dict3=defaultdict(list)
dict1=defaultdict(list)
pattern="QWL"
rd_case= "Digital"
setup_temp = "0C"
readout_temp = "0C"
address=[]

def tde_file():
  with open(r'C:\Gert_batch file\DOE_parsing\Thebe\DOE 4 - 5K\NEW SFR\PF\tde\MRB_QWL_0c_Digital_PS60c_TC1798.tde', 'rb') as f:
    for line in f:
        pattern_tde = ":TEST_RESULT"
        if pattern_tde in line:

            tde_addr = ':TEST_RESULT (\d+); addr: ([0-9A-Za-z]{10})'
            x0 =re.match(tde_addr, line)

            if x0:
                address_tde = x0.group(2)
                tde_addr_1 = 'cfp_(vqs|vcs)_m(\d+) \// HB05_SB255'
                x1 = re.search(tde_addr_1,line)

                tde_addr_2 = 'cfp_(vqs|vcs)_m\dm\d_(vth\d.\d) \// HB05_SB255'
                x2 = re.search(tde_addr_2,line)

                tde_addrs_1 = '(DTS_)value_(before|after)_test_(start|finish)'
                y0 = re.search(tde_addrs_1,line)

                if x1:
                    hlp_s = x1.group(2).zfill(2)
                    identifier =  x1.group(1)+"_m"+hlp_s

                if x2:
                    identifier =  x2.group(1)+"_m"+x2.group(2)

                try:
                    tde_addr_3 = '(SBE|DBE)|(Number of (\ds) bit fail) \// HB05_SB255'
                    hlp_s = re.search(tde_addr_3,line).group(1)
                    if hlp_s:
                              dict1[pattern,rd_case,address_tde]=identifier+"_"+hlp_s

                except AttributeError:pass

                try:
                    tde_addr_3 = '(SBE|DBE)|(Number of (\ds) bit fail) \// HB05_SB255'
                    hlp_s = re.search(tde_addr_3,line).group(3)
                    if hlp_s:
                        dict1[pattern,rd_case,address_tde]=identifier+"_"+hlp_s

                except AttributeError: pass

                try:
                    if y0.group(1) and y0.group(3):
                        dict1[pattern,rd_case,address_tde]=y0.group(1)+y0.group(3)+"_temp"
                except AttributeError: pass

def evaluate_lot_wxy(trf_dev_id_pattern):
  import re
  binary_value = ""
  dev_id_status = False

  line = trf_dev_id_pattern
  dev_id = 'Device ID: ([0-9a-zA-Z]{10}) ([0-9a-zA-Z]{10}) ([0-9a-zA-Z]{10}) ([0-9a-zA-Z]{10})$'
  hex_inp1 = re.search(dev_id,line)
  #print hex_inp1.group()
  hex_inp2 = hex_inp1.group(4)+hex_inp1.group(3)+hex_inp1.group(2)+hex_inp1.group(1)
  hex_inp3 =  re.sub('0x', '', hex_inp2)
  #print hex_inp3
  for i,val in enumerate(str(hex_inp3)):
     binary_value1=str(bin(int(val,16))[2:]).zfill(4)
     binary_value = str(binary_value) + str(binary_value1)
     #print binary_value

  wafer_val = binary_value[90:96]
  wafer = int(wafer_val,2)
  y_pos_val = binary_value[106:113]
  y_pos = int(y_pos_val,2)
  x_pos_val = binary_value[98:105]
  x_pos = int(x_pos_val,2)
  year_val = binary_value[63:67]
  year = int(year_val,2)
  production_week_val = binary_value[67:73]
  production_week = int(production_week_val,2)
  serial_no_val = binary_value[73:83]
  serial_no=int(serial_no_val,2)
  lot ="ZA"+str(year)+str(production_week)+str(serial_no)
  if (1 <= wafer <= 25) and (1<= x_pos <= 65) and (1 <= y_pos <= 65):
    dev_id_status = True
  return lot,wafer,x_pos,y_pos,dev_id_status

tde_file()
with open(r"C:\Gert_batch file\DOE_parsing\Thebe\DOE 4 - 5K\NEW SFR\PF\1k Cycling\Results_452_13384\Result Files\452_20170111_021021_TC1798_MRB_QWL_0c_Digital_PS60c_1021002999.trf") as f1:
        lines = f1.read()
        socket_position_status = False
        dev_id_status = False
        CB_noS_status = False
        trf_val_flag = False
        for m in re.finditer(r'Socket:(.*?)ART: 0xB00017EC DRT: 0x00000000\n', lines,flags=re.DOTALL):
            x1 = ('%s' % (m.group(0)))

            for line in x1.splitlines():
                if "Socket:" in line:
                    trf_addr = 'Socket: (\d+)$'
                    x0 =re.match(trf_addr, line)
                    try:
                        if x0.group(1).zfill(3):
                            socket_position = x0.group(1).zfill(3)
                            socket_position_status = True
                            #print socket_position


                    except AttributeError: pass

                elif "Device ID:" in line:
                    dev_id = 'Device ID: ([0-9a-zA-Z]{10}) ([0-9a-zA-Z]{10}) ([0-9a-zA-Z]{10}) ([0-9a-zA-Z]{10})$'
                    x1 = re.search(dev_id,line)
                    try:
                        if  x1.group(1) and x1.group(1) and x1.group(1) and x1.group(1):
                            trf_dev_id_pattern = x1.group()#x1.group(4)+x1.group(3)+x1.group(2)+x1.group(1)
                            lot_wafer_x_y = evaluate_lot_wxy(trf_dev_id_pattern)
                            dev_id_status = lot_wafer_x_y[4]
                            #print lot_wafer_x_y

                    except AttributeError: pass

                elif "CB:" in line:
                    CB_pat = 'CB: (\d+)\/'
                    x2 = re.search(CB_pat,line)
                    try:
                        if  x2.group(1):
                            CB_no = x2.group(1)
                            CB_noS_status = True
                            #print CB_noS_status
                    except AttributeError: pass

                elif"ART:" in line:
                    regex = re.search("ART: ([0-9A-Za-z]{10}) DRT: ([0-9A-Za-z]{10}$)",line)
                    #print line
                    try:
                        if regex.group(1) and regex.group(2):
                            for key1,val1 in dict1.iteritems():
                                if regex.group(1) in key1:
                                    #print "Address:"+regex.group(1)
                                    hlp_a = val1
                                    hlp_b = hlp_a.split("_")
                                    identifier = hlp_b[0]
                                    fail_class = hlp_b[1]
                                    key_addtional = hlp_b[2]
                                    val = regex.group(2)
                                    value = int(val[3:],16)
                                    trf_val_flag = True
                                    if dev_id_status and trf_val_flag and CB_noS_status:
                                        dict3[rd_case,pattern,setup_temp,readout_temp,CB_no,socket_position,fail_class,identifier,key_addtional]= value
                                        continue


                    except AttributeError: pass

    #elif socket_position_status and dev_id_status and CB_noS_status and trf_val_flag:
        #dict3[rd_case,pattern,setup_temp,readout_temp,socket_position,fail_class,identifier]= value

print len(dict3.keys())
```